# What would be the pros and cons of requiring major versions to be forward compatible?

Tags: versioning, semantic-versioning, liskov-substitution, backward-compatibility, forward-compatibility

So I was learning about forward compatibility, and I was wondering if you could warn a "dependent" that a dependency is backward compatible, but not forward compatible*, and vice-versa.

The SemVer specification requires that:

> [7.](https://semver.org/#spec-item-7) Minor version Y (x.Y.z | x > 0) MUST be incremented if **new, backwards compatible functionality** [emphasis mine] is introduced to the public API. [...]
>
> [8.](https://semver.org/#spec-item-8) Major version X (X.y.z | X > 0) MUST be incremented if any backwards incompatible changes are introduced to the public API. **It MAY include minor** and patch **level changes.** [emphasis mine] [...]

To me, it means that:

- You must increment the minor version when you do a backward compatible but not forward compatible* change. Indeed, if you introduced a "new [...] functionality [...] to the public API" and dependents upgrade the dependency and use it, the dependency can't guarantee that downgrading won't break any dependent, as a mirrored version of backward compatibility. So adding a "new [...] functionality [...] to the public API" is backward compatible and not forward compatible*, and I make the supposition that any backward compatible and not forward compatible* change is, in a way, adding "new [...] functionality [...] to the public API", because I don't see any counter-example (and other reasons I could explain if needed), making them basically equivalent.
- You must increment the major version when you do a not backward compatible change. It can be forward compatible*, or not.
- You must increment the patch version when you do a backward compatible and forward compatible* change, by elimination (and the same other reasons I could explain if needed).

Suppose that I'm right, and that any change that is both not backward compatible and not forward compatible* can be separated into two successive changes, one backward compatible and the other forward compatible* (or the other way around).
It would mean that you could always separate the not backward compatible but forward compatible* changes from the others, and never have a change that is both not backward compatible and not forward compatible*.
So you could redefine:

- the major version as a forward compatible* version including at least one not backward compatible change
- the minor version as a backward compatible version including at least one not forward compatible* change.

It would mean that any new major version `M.0.p` of a dependency can be downgraded safely by dependents, even until the last minor version of the preceding major version, let's call it `(M-1).m.0`.

Suppose that I'm right.
**Would it be beneficial or useless to the dependents to know that a version of a dependency is guaranteed to be forward compatible*?

What would be the pros and cons of that additional constraint to SemVer?**

(verifying my reasoning is not the purpose of this question, I know that I'm overthinking, but I just want to know if this reasoning is useful in any way or not, however I would appreciate to have your opinion)

---

EDIT: Anywhere there is a "*" after "forward compatible", I meant "safely downgradable".
Indeed, when a version is backward compatible, it means that the previous version is safely upgradable.
So when a version is forward compatible, it means that the *next* version is safely downgradable.
It also means that you can't guarantee that a version is forward compatible before the next version is out.
So you can guarantee that a new version is backward compatible or safely downgradable, but you can't guarantee that it's forward compatible or safely upgradable *yet*.

Answer (score 4):

Almost all changes are, by their very nature, forward incompatible:

- If I fix a bug and release patch, then downgrading will introduce that bug.
- If I introduce a new feature, then downgrading will remove that feature and so potentially leave the code in a non-compilable state.
- If I make a breaking change, then that change will be breaking in either direction, eg I change `Foo` to `Bar`, then use `Bar`, I cannot then downgrade to the previous version.

As you say in your comment, the one exception to this is by using a minor change to introduce an alias and then a major change to remove the original and leave just the alias. In this specific situation, the major change is forward compatible.

So we could change 8 to:

> Major version X (X.y.z | X > 0) MUST be incremented if any backwards incompatible changes are introduced to the public API. It MAY include minor and patch level changes. *It MAY include forward compatible changes*. Patch and minor version MUST be reset to 0 when major version is incremented.

But since we can only say "may" there, as forward compatibility is an edge case, what would this achieve other than to leave people confused and asking what that forward compatible clause was for?

Comment: I disagree with you: removing a public functionality, for example, is forward compatible: downgrading will just add it again, but the dependent won't use it.

Comment: Moreover, "substantial new functionality or improvements [...] introduced within the private code" (from SemVer) won't change the public API, so won't break anything. It would qualify as a patch within my version of SemVer.

Comment: Forward compatibility is just a mirrored version of backward compatibility, where you downgrade instead of upgrading, so if a backward compatible change is possible, a forward compatible change is too.

Comment: Finally, as I said in my question, you can decompose at least some forward and backward incompatible changes into a forward and a backward compatible changes, and renaming a function is one of those: you can first add `bar` as an alias to `foo` (backward compatible), then remove `foo` (forward compatible).

Comment: @CidTori, Regarding, "*substantial new functionality or improvements [...] introduced within the private code*". If its new functionality introduced purely within private code, then its not accessible via the API and thus is dead code that should never have been introduced in the first place. Substantial improvements must have an affect on the API, otherwise they aren't substantial improvements. For example, changes to the private code might halve the execution time of a function. Downgrading would then double that time, which could adversely affect my app. So that's not forward compatible.

Comment: @CidTori, interestingly though, you are right regarding your `bar` to `foo` change using two releases. It is possible, with care, to make a major change forward compatible. I shall update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Even if the performances drop, if it's not guaranteed by the dependency, your app won't break, so it's still compatible. Incompatibility is about breaking changes, not slowing changes. And a "substantial new functionality or improvements [...] introduced within the private code" can be a lot of other things, like a huge refactoring, adding some internal used functions, some caching, some paralelism, things that are huge for the developper but transparent for the dependent.

Comment: However, if you improve the performances, and that improvement is part of the new public contract of the API, then it's not forward compatible indeed.

Comment: @CidTori, "*huge for the developper but transparent for the dependent*" is not a justification for a change. If the API isn't changing in someway (even if its just for performance reasons), then don't inflict a new version on people as it brings no benefit.

Comment: I do not disagree with you, but "substantial new functionality or improvements [...] introduced within the private code" is specified in SemVer's spec', and for minor versions...: https://semver.org/#spec-item-7